# Zoom image on swipe

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager

I am working on a task where I have to zoom image on swipe, my images are swiping and also I have put some zoom animations on it. So it is zooming too but not the way I want it to. I want that, when I swipe the image; the next image come but first show as zoomed and then in its on own way. I am failed to do so. Need an example. Thank You. Below is my code for it:-

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LinearLayout linearlay=new LinearLayout(context);
        linearlay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearlay.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(image_id[position]);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.zoom_in_out);
            v.startAnimation(animation);
                return false;
            }
        });
        linearlay.addView(imageView,0);
        TextView textView=new TextView(context);
        textView.setText("Image: "+image_id[position]); 
        linearlay.addView(textView);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(linearlay);
        return linearlay;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you need to test for various types of touches within your onTouch() method. You are only testing for a single touch.  Check for a swipe, or a two finger gesture such as pinch or zoom.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html